# Alter plot of likert() to display individual summary values on bars rather than hi/low

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

I've developed a series of plots using likert() to display the results of survey questions. In general this works great, but for one particular question, the quantities against individual responses is significant, so the default behaviour of likert() to display low/centre/hi summaries doesn't quite work for me.

I'm aware I could revert this all to base R and plot using summaries, but what I'm wondering is if there's some simple way to modify this plot to achieve this while still using likert()?

Here's a reproducible code sample:

```
# Ingest data to make reproducible example:

climate_experience_data <- structure(list(Q25_self_and_family = c(4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2), Q25_local_area = c(3, 
3, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 3, 
4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
4, 3), Q25_uk = c(4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 
2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Q25_outside_uk = c(4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# load libraries:

require(tidyverse)
require(likert)

# Q25 - generate diverging stacked bar chart using likert()
q25_data <- select(climate_experience_data, Q25_self_and_family:Q25_outside_uk)
names(q25_data) <- c("You and your family in the UK", "People in your local area or city", "The UK as a whole", "Your family and/or friends living outside the UK")
# Set up levels text for question responses
q25_levels <- paste(c("not at all", "somewhat", "moderately", "very", "extremely"),  
                    "serious")
q25_likert_table <- q25_data %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                factor, ordered = TRUE, levels = 1:5, labels=q25_levels)) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>%

# make plot:

plot(q25_likert_table, wrap=20, text.size=3, ordered=FALSE, low.color='#B18839', high.color='#590048') + 
  ggtitle(title) +
  labs(title = "How serious a threat do you think \nclimate change poses to the following?", y="") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) + 
  theme_ipsum_rc() +
  theme()
```

And an image of how things currently display:

[image]

And a quick ugly mock-up of what I'd be going for:

[image]

Comment: On further investigation, I think I should be able to achieve this by adding `plot.percents=TRUE, plot.percent.low=FALSE, 
     plot.percent.high=FALSE, plot.percent.neutral=FALSE` to the plot(). However, I'm hitting another error `Error in ddply(results[results$value > 0, ], .(Item), transform, pos = cumsum(value) -  : 
  could not find function "ddply"` because of an unresolved bug in the likert() code: [https://github.com/jbryer/likert/issues/114]

Comment: I've just confirmed this is the issue and proposed a commit on the github for likert().

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to address this is by changing the plot() command to include a new set of parameters, to add in titles `plot.percents=TRUE` and remove the low/neutral/high default summaries: `plot.percent.low=FALSE, plot.percent.high=FALSE, plot.percent.neutral=FALSE`

Like this:

```
plot(q25_likert_table, wrap=20, text.size=3, ordered=FALSE, low.color='#B18839', high.color='#590048', plot.percents=TRUE, plot.percent.low=FALSE, plot.percent.high=FALSE, plot.percent.neutral=FALSE) + 
  ggtitle(title) +
  labs(title = "How serious a threat do you think \nclimate change poses to the following?", y="") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) + 
  theme_ipsum_rc() +
  theme()
```

However, it's worth noting that there is a bug in likert() which will throw an error for some users. For more, see [here](https://github.com/jbryer/likert/issues/114).